# Limiting a query before joining tables, using sub query table for join

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I am trying to speed up a query by limiting the size of the first table before I join it.

Original code which seems to takes too long to run

```
SELECT 
    f.store_id,
    f.promotion_sku,
    dt.calendar_month_end,
    SUM(redemption_voucher_count),
    SUM(redemption_voucher_value),
    SUM(redemption_customer_is_new),
    pt.promotion_super_type
FROM
    (((vouchers.redemptions f
    INNER JOIN retail.stores rs ON f.store_id = rs.store_id)
    INNER JOIN vouchers.promotions p ON p.promotion_sku = f.promotion_sku
        AND p.country_id = rs.country_id)
    INNER JOIN vouchers.promotion_types pt ON pt.promotion_type_id = p.promotion_type_id),
    retail_analysis.date_d dt
WHERE
    f.date_id >= 20181201
        AND f.date_id <= 20190131
        AND TRUE
        AND redemption_date = dt.date_full
        AND f.store_id IS NOT NULL
        AND f.promotion_sku IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY f.store_id , f.promotion_sku , dt.calendar_month_end , pt.promotion_super_type
```

I have tried limiting the date before I join in the below but I get vouchers.f table does not exists. Is what I am doing possible?

```
SELECT 
    f.store_id,
    f.promotion_sku,
    dt.calendar_month_end,
    SUM(redemption_voucher_count),
    SUM(redemption_voucher_value),
    SUM(redemption_customer_is_new),
    pt.promotion_super_type
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM vouchers.redemptions x WHERE x.date_id >= 20181201 AND  x.date_id <= 20190131) AS f,
    (((f INNER JOIN retail.stores rs ON f.store_id = rs.store_id
        INNER JOIN vouchers.promotions p ON p.promotion_sku = f.promotion_sku
        AND p.country_id = rs.country_id
        INNER JOIN vouchers.promotion_types pt ON pt.promotion_type_id = p.promotion_type_id))),
        retail_analysis.date_d dt
WHERE
        TRUE
        AND redemption_date = dt.date_full
        AND f.store_id IS NOT NULL
        AND f.promotion_sku IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY f.store_id , f.promotion_sku , dt.calendar_month_end , pt.promotion_super_type
```

Comment: Replace `f` in `(((f INNER JOIN` with the subquery -- `((((SELECT * FROM vouchers.redemptions x WHERE x.date_id >= 20181201 AND  x.date_id <= 20190131) AS f INNER JOIN`. But your strategy might have the negative effect of what you hope. It's possible, that you prevent the use of indexes with such a subquery. Speaking of indexes, you're already through with checking if the existing indexes are optimal for the query? Most of the time that's far more important than rewriting the query.

Comment: Ok i'll give that a go - I have three index on the columns i thought i was joining, store date_id and promo sku - however in this query the AND redemption_date = dt.date_full is there also, so i'm indexing redemption date.

Comment: Three indexes for three columns indicate that you probably haven't though about compound indexes, which could help more. If you want suggestions for that you should post the structure of the tables involved in the query as `CREATE TABLE` statements the `CREATE INDEX` statements of all indexes on these tables (unless defined inline in the `CREATE TABLE` statements) and the execution plan of the query. Edit your question to do so. Don't post in as comments.

Comment: Ok i've had a read about compound indexes and will give it a go, local server is crashing atm when indexing, thanks for the advice as to why the sub query was causing an error, this no longer happens.